# iOS8で動いていたアプリをiOS9.0.2にインストールしようとすると、「現在ダウンロードできません」と表示される

Tags: ios

はじめまして、

iOSのEnterPrise版を利用しています。

iOS8にはインストールできますが、iOS9.0.2にインストールすると
『「Appをダウンロードできません」"hoge"は現在ダウンロードできません』と表示されます。

XcodeのDeviceLogを確認すると

```
Nov 26 19:00:43 iPad itunesstored[105] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Failed to install application: country.hoge.hogehoge.hoge; /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-4589859272339109610/9170660669514305598; Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=143 "(null)"
Nov 26 19:00:43 iPad itunesstored[105] <Warning>: [Download]: Fail download: -4589859272339109610 after error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=143 "(null)"
Nov 26 19:00:43 iPad itunesstored[105] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace] Install complete for download: -4589859272339109610 result: Failed
Nov 26 19:02:30 iPad syncdefaultsd[270] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x15c51de00>
Nov 26 19:02:46 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Disabling lock screen media controls updates for screen turning off.
Nov 26 19:02:46 iPad backboardd[55] <Notice>: [HID] [MT] MTSimpleHIDManager::setPropertyInternal detection mode: 3->255
Nov 26 19:02:47 iPad sharingd[175] <Notice>: 19:02:47.255 : BTLE scanning stopped
Nov 26 19:02:47 iPad MobileSafari[255] <Warning>:  ** -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] ** unhandled action -> <FBSSceneSnapshotAction: 0x140092640>
```

と表示されます。

どなたか対処方法をご存知ないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: DLページのURL／plistファイルを指定するURL／plistファイル内でipaファイルを指定するURL　いずれもhttpsでの指定になっていますでしょうか？今手元で再現できなかったのですが、以前iOS7.1ではインストールできたものの、iOS8(9だったかもしれません)ではインストールできなかったということがありました。調査した結果、plist内でipaファイルを指定するURLがhttp表記で、sが抜けていたというミスの際に外見上同じような動作だったような記憶があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
URLの表記は問題ありません。
実は最近までインストールできていました。
Identifierを変更することになりその後、インストールが
できなくなりました。

Identifierを作成して、Developer, Distributionを作成し
コンパイルしてアップロードした後からこの現象になりました。
エラーログを見ると以前のIdentifierが表示されています。
ideveloper上では旧Identifierは削除しているので、紐付いていないと
思うのですが以前のidentifierがエラーログに表示されてしまいます。
プロジェクトファイルもクリーンしていますし、、、
XcodeのGeneral info buildsetting も関連しているところは
変更しているつもりです。
林檎社に聞いてみてもすっきりした回答は得られませんでした。

テストまでしていただいたみたいで感謝です！

Comment: もう既に試し済みかと思いますが、自分も似たような経験したのでご参考までに。

・一度iPhone/iPad実機から該当のアプリを削除し、もう一度インストールしてみる

・manifest.plistを生成し直してみる
Xcode7でipaを書き出し、OTAで配信まで
http://qiita.com/nofrmm/items/797ab6fc89af3ade7a27

・開発機のProvisioning Profileを一度初期化する
Provisional Profileの追加と削除
http://qiita.com/noppefoxwolf/items/cca1dca314db376c2310